# get specific index from list of list inside a map

Tags: javascript, groovy

I cant figure how to do the following in javascript

In groovy, if I want to iterate over a map and inside that map the value is a list of lists, then get a specific index from a list of lists i.e. the following code will work

`def total = value.collect { it.get(0) }*.toInteger().sum()`

the spread operator is used convert all the retrieved data to integer and then get the total using sum

How do to this in Javascript?

Comment: Can you show a short example of the real data, JS [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)s are not indexed (numeric keys are possible, though).

Comment: i am unable to provide the data right now but to clarify, I used an object i.e. {} to store the key value pairs. the value is a "list of lists". for example, if I am inside a loop for the object  i.e. for(var key in grouping ), i can iterate the value using a standard for loop i.e.  for ( var a = 0; a < line.size(); a++). inside the inner loop  I can get the data that I want i.e. (line.get(a).get(0)). But in my example in groovy script above I can do that using collect and the spread operator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Straight from the JS-console:

```
[ ['1', 44], ['3', 55], ['42']].map( x => parseInt( x[ 0 ] ) ).reduce( ( res, x ) => res + x, 0 )

//or for an JS-Object/Map

Object.values( { a:'1', b:'3', c:'42' } ).map( x => parseInt( x ) ).reduce( ( res, x ) => res + x, 0 )

// or with plain JS Funtions

[ ['1', 44], ['3', 55], ['42']].map( function(x){ return parseInt( x[ 0 ] ) } ).reduce( function( res, x ){ return res + x }, 0 )


>> 46
```

Here the `map` is the counterpart of Groovy's `collect`, and the `reduce` replaces Groovy's `inject`. A `sum` shortcut doesn't exist in JS unfortunately...

Comment: Thanks for this. Its working if i test it in online testing tools. but unfortunately I think the javascript engine (Rhino 1.7 R4) that im stuck with is incompatible with this.

Comment: you have replace the lambdas with plain JS functions. see the updated answer